# python command line arguments have to be wrapped by quote marks?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm encountering this issue, and sort of found out the solution. However, I don't understand why it behaves like this.

Suppose I have a script1.py to run, which requires two inputs from the command line, a path and a date. For /root/x/y*, there are two folders, i.e. /root/x/y1/ and /root/x/y2/. And under both folders, there are a folder of 20160621.

The script looks like this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    start_time = time.time()
    print sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    main(expPath = sys.argv[1], expDate = sys.argv[2])
```

If I call the script by

```
python script1.py /root/x/y*/ 20160621
```

I expected to get printout of

```
/root/x/y*/ 20160621
```

However, sometimes, I'm getting

```
/root/x/y1/  /root/x/y2/
```

If I call the script by quoting both arguments, it works as expected.

```
python script1.py '/root/x/y*/' '20160621'
```

Any particular reason or explanation for such a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a Python issue. This is an issue regarding the command line.

When you pass `/root/x/y*/` on the command line, you are not literally passing that argument. You are using something called "globbing". The command line is automatically expanding that to `'/root/x/y1/'  '/root/x/y2/'` before passing it to your script. When you place them in quotes, then you are passing the literal text, and not allowing the command line to glob the text, so it acts as you would expect.

I would recommend that you allow the command line to handle the globbing where practical. Many shells have quite advanced globbing abilities, and end users will rely on this ability to pass filenames to your script.